# How to properly escape double quotes on AWX extra-var

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I'm trying to create a playbook that launch a powershell script using awx and ansible.

My playbook looks like that:

```
- name: Awesome name
  hosts: all

  tasks:
    - name : Execute script
      win_shell: powershell.exe script.ps1 "{{computer_name}}" "{{ip}}" "{{words}}" "{{email}}"
```

In ansible, I setted up those 4 variables. The problem comes with the ip variable. I would like the script to execute like this on the remote computer:

```
powershell.exe script.ps1 "mycomputer" "192.168.0.1,192.168.0.2,192.168.0.3" "net,up,down" "myemail@secure.com"
```

The problem is that the double quotes never stay during the script execution and it always end up with error like: Cannot process argument - transformation on parameter 'ip'. Cannot convert value to type System.String.

I don't know how to keep the double quotes in the variable. I have tried escaping the quotes, using single quotes, etc... But nothing seems to work.

Does someone have an idea ? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer...

For powershell to actually read your parameters right, you need to use the "-File" to specify the path of the script. Otherwise, other parameters may be inexactly parsed.

So I changed my yaml to :

```
- name: Awesome name
  hosts: all

  tasks:
    - name : Execute script
      win_shell: powershell.exe -File script.ps1 "{{computer_name}}" "{{ip}}" "{{words}}" "{{email}}"
```

And it works now.